# What happens to surplus referee reports?

Tags: peer-review, editors, journal-workflow

As far as I understand, it is commonplace for editors to invite M reviewers when N < M would suffice. After N reports arrive, they take a decision and inform the authors. What happens to the N+1<sup>st</sup>, N+2<sup>nd</sup>, ... referee reports that arrive after the decision has been taken?

As a referee, I have only been told “thanks, we won’t need your report anymore” a very small number of times, and as an author I’ve never been told “look, there’s one more report for you”. So I wonder what happens in practice.

EDIT: I have in mind journals, not conferences. A conference is more driven by deadlines, probably.

Comment: *as an author I’ve never been told “look, there’s one more report for you”* – I have.

Comment: In practice, the journals I where I know the process have a deadline for the reviewers to hand in. If they have N reviews at that deadline, those are the N used and the reviewers who hand in later might not have any effect. If they have less than N, they would send out reminders and extend the deadline. If they have M>N reviews at the deadline, all of them will be used in the decision and given to the author.

Comment: @skymningen So the editor discards the surplus reports? Even when they suggest meaningful corrections that may be useful to the author?

Comment: I think so. They should have to. Otherwise, how would anything ever go on? What if there is one more reviewer, but they are not responsive? How long would you wait for them to respond before publishing the paper without their input? Exactly, as long as the original deadline was, that was what it is for. Also, an editor is not a stand-in for scientific communication. If it is not double-blind and the reviewer thinks their input is important for the authors they could contact the corresponding author.

Comment: @skymningen As a referee, how can I take the decision to contact the authors, if I don't even know when my comments have been discarded and when they haven't?

Comment: @FedericoPoloni As I said, there is a deadline. Everything arriving before the deadline is used, everything after it is not. You know if you are on time You are told to hand in your review before this deadline. It is a deadline for the reviewers, not the editor or authors.

Comment: @skymningen Anyway, what you write looks like an answer; could you please formulate one?

Comment: I would say it is anecdotal. Also, I cannot pinpoint any journals specific rules about this, I have just observed it and heard it mentioned in a personal conversation between my supervisor and a colleague of his who is an editor for a journal.

Comment: @FedericoPoloni - the journals I'm familiar with would want the request to contact the authors of a paper you reviewed to go through the editor anyway. At the least that means that all parties are aware of the communication and that there is no 'back door' that could impact the integrity of the review process.

Comment: @skymningen Why not post your answers as answers, rather than comments?

Comment: I would really appreciate if we would get some first hand information from actual editors in the answers!

Comment: As a reviewer I will now enquire as for I never thought of referees overbooking.  If I do accept,  unless I not fulfil the schedule, ignoring reminder from the editors, my work should be taken into account. I never had the impression of my suggestions being ignored.  Therefore it is likely that there is not redundancy in N or I was never the overbooked one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From my experience, things happen differently. Comments do highlight it correctly.

Initially, N reviews are solicited by the editor. If they disagree (or, I have to assume, some reviewers miss their deadlines), more reviews are solicited. I've been reviewer #5 few times.

Typical values for N are:

- 2, with third as a tie-break – a typical grant application review scheme;
- 3, with 4 or even 5 as a tie-break - seen more often with journal papers.

Comment: So you mean that typically N=M? There is no "referee overbooking"? So what is written [here](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/101539/958), for instance, is inaccurate?

Comment: In my experience (chair of a small-ish track at a conference, IPC member few times, reviewer since, like, 2008): there might be an "overbooking" in a sense that M>N, but if more reviews are requested than needed and they all arrive, all are regarded. So no "overbooking" in the sense "your review is not valid".

Comment: I think it's important to differentiate between a "request to review" and actual reviews. Sure, I'd ask more than N people to review. Then few decline, I'd still need to come up with at least N. If I get M>N it's not a problem. But all reviews that were submitted are considered. It's __not__ like "oh, we got 10 reviews, so let's cherry-pick 4 out of there."

Comment: I have heard some editors only "overbook" during "tough times" when they admit that many reviewers are either very busy or on holiday.

Answer (score 1):

In my experience, typically the editor doesn't make a decision immediately after N reviews arrive. Instead (s)he waits for all the reviewers who've agreed to review to complete. This way the only chance of having surplus referee reports is if a reviewer agrees, does not submit by the review due date, editor makes a decision, and *then* the reviewer submits. This is rare, and gets even rarer the longer the editor waits after the due date.

If it does happen, and the original decision was 'revise', we write to the authors with "here's another review, please take that into account in your revision". If the original decision was 'accept' or 'reject', then the review is effectively wasted.